# Integral curve on tangential field

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, curves

I'm struggling a bit in finding the integralcurve of a given tangential field. Let's say we have (easy example, I think) the following tangential field: $X=(x+y) \delta_x + (y-x) \delta_y$.

How do I have to proceed to get the integral curve?

I know that I have to find an equation like [here](http://idv.sinica.edu.tw/ftliang/diff_geom/*diff_geometry(I)/10.16/integralcurves.pdf):
(Example 1.b). But how should the equation look like for my example? (And why?)
I think this information should be enough for me to solve the task.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Can you write down the equation for the integral curve w.r.t your vector field?

Comment: I edited and re-formulated the question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the notations in the note, let $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ be the integral curve for $X$. Then the equation for the integral curve would become $x'(t)=x(t)+y(t), y'(t)=y(t)-y(t)$ in this case. (It seems a typo here?) Then you can find the solution for this ODE as this is a system of linear ODE. (More accurately, you can claim that there exists a unique solution given an initial condition, but finding an explicit form of the solution may be hard in general.)

---

Edit: After finding the system of ODEs for the integral curve, all you need to consult with is some techniques in standard ODE course; for example, in the current example, the ODE is 1st order homogeneous and linear, so you can rewrite the given ODE as

$\mathbf{x}'=A\mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{x}=(x(t),y(t))^t$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1 \\ 
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$.

And then the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1\pm i$ whose corresponding eigenvectors are $(1 ,\pm i)^t$ respectively. Thus the general solution of this ODE is $\mathbf{x}=ae^{(1+i)t}(1,i)^t+be^{(1-i)t}(1,-i)^t$ for constants $a,b$ that satisfy the initial condition(say, a point where your integral curve starts at).

Comment: Yeah there was in fact a typo, sorry. It should be: $y'(t) = y(t)-x(t)$. I don't see the ODE yet. Which equations do you use for the ODE? Could you please show me this step? Thanks a lot!

Comment: We know: 
$x'(t) = x(t)+y(t) $,
$y'(t) = y(t) - x(t)$.
How can I use this information for the ODE?

Comment: @JohnD Then you must solve the ODE to obtain the explicite form of the solution. I have added the flow of the logic in my answer but you must consult with ODE textbook(any undergraduate level one would suffice) if you're not familiar with the method here.